# Ambiguous reference to member 'download(_:destination:)' in alamofire download.swift file after migration

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, migration, alamofire

Recently i just converted swift 2.3 project to 3.2 , alamofire also got converted, and i received many issues solved most of them, now i am stuck with the given two issue

```
/**
    Creates a request for downloading from the specified URL request.

    If `startRequestsImmediately` is `true`, the request will have `resume()` called before being returned.

    - parameter URLRequest:  The URL request
    - parameter destination: The closure used to determine the destination of the downloaded file.

    - returns: The created download request.
*/

public func download(_ URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return download(.request(URLRequest.URLRequest), destination: destination)
}
```

getting issue like

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'download(_:destination:)'
```

and same issue for the resume data

```
// MARK: Resume Data

/**
    Creates a request for downloading from the resume data produced from a previous request cancellation.

    If `startRequestsImmediately` is `true`, the request will have `resume()` called before being returned.

    - parameter resumeData:  The resume data. This is an opaque data blob produced by `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` 
                             when a task is cancelled. See `NSURLSession -downloadTaskWithResumeData:` for 
                             additional information.
    - parameter destination: The closure used to determine the destination of the downloaded file.

    - returns: The created download request.
*/
public func download(_ resumeData: Data, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return download(.resumeData(resumeData), destination: destination)
}
```

searched everywhere for the solution, but didn't find, please help me in this,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `download` for `urlRequest`

```
open func download(
    _ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible,
    to destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination? = nil)
    -> Request
{
    return download(urlRequest.URLRequest, to: destination)
}
```

Below is the `download` for `resumeData`:

```
open func download(
    resumingWith resumeData: Data,
    to destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination? = nil)
    -> Request
{
    return download(resumingWith: resumeData, to: destination)
}
```

For the one which you mentioned in comments :

```
public func download(_ URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.download(URLRequest.URLRequest, to: destination)
}

public func download(resumeData data: Data, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.download(resumingWith: data, to: destination)
}
```

Comment: tried your solution getting the error :- Use of undeclared type 'DownloadRequest' and Value of type 'URLRequestConvertible' has no member 'asURLRequest'

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'DownloadRequest' for Download Request and 'URLRequestConvertible' has no member 'asURLRequest' for urlRequest

Comment: now got this errors:- on line `return download(.request(urlRequest.URLRequest), to: destination)` issue as `Type 'URLRequestConvertible' has no member 'request'` and on line `return download(nil, to: destination, failedWith: error)` issue as `Ambiguous reference to member 'download(_:destination:)'`, on line `return download(.resumeData(resumeData), to: destination)` issue as `Type 'URLRequestConvertible' has no member 'resumeData'`

Comment: and also warning as `'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block` thought this would require that is why commented it

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: That worked but that caused an error at different location in alamofire.swift file `public func download(_ URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.download(URLRequest, destination: destination)
}` issue as `Argument labels '(_:, destination:)' do not match any available overloads` same issue with the `public func download(resumeData data: Data, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.download(data, destination: destination)
}`

Comment: Download for urlrequest syntax is changed. You have to call as ‘download(urlrequest, to: destination)’

Comment: This is not because of the above fix it got changed in Alamofire latest version

Comment: please suggest me ,how to do it?